# Why this Interpolation search algorithm correctly works for only 1 digit values? ( does not work with key greater than 10)

Tags: c++, algorithm, interpolation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21};
    int first, last, pos, key;

    first = 0;
    last = (sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0])) - 1;
    cout << "Enter the key value:\t" << endl;
    cin >> key;

    //The search code starts from here
    while(first <= last && key >= first && key <= last) {
        pos = first + (((last - first)/(arr[last] - arr[first])) * (key - arr[first]));

        if(key < arr[pos]) {
            last = pos - 1;
        }
        else if(key > arr[pos]) {
            first = pos + 1;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Found the value at index:\t" << pos << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if the value is not found
    if(first > last) {
        cout << "The value is not found." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This algorithm works from zero to 10. However, whenever I am inputting 11 or more, the code is somehow leaking which I am not able to figure out. I am new to programming, thus, I am facing some difficulty.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try to **step through** your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you divide two integer values then if the first value (numerator) less then the second one (denominator) you'l get zero. Then you need to increase the value of numerator by doing multiplication first. Try to use this code:

```
pos = first + (last - first) * (key - arr[first]) / (arr[last] - arr[first]);
```

Or honestly use floating point calculations:

```
//The search code starts from here
while(first <= last && key >= first && key <= last) {
    pos = (int)((double)first + (double)(last - first) * (double)(key - arr[first]) / (double)(arr[last] - arr[first]));

    if(key < arr[pos]) {
        last = pos - 1;
    }
    else if(key > arr[pos]) {
        first = pos + 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Found the value at index:\t" << pos << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippets, without, any, explanation are useless as an answer (do not provide any more knowledge, as to the reason for the problem, to the OP).

Comment: Thank you. Added comment

Comment: Sorry, Doesn't work. I just copied your line of code replacing with mine, but the same error remains. Moreover, using double pos gives an error: invalid types 'double [11][double]' for array subscription.

Comment: get out a pencil and a sheet of paper and hand trace that code for an input value of 11.  I did it 5 minutes...why dont you do that?